# does anyone know how to un-hide the breakpoint feature in visual studios?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I was using the breakpoint feature in visual studio for mac and I accidentally hid the tab for breakpoint and now I can't find it for debugging purposes. Does anyone know how to make it appear again?

It was next to the locals, watch, and thread tabs.

what my visual studios looks like now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN3i4.jpg

Comment: Figured it out go to  view< debug pads< breakpoint

Comment: Please post it as an answer as a quick reference so it helps others who have similar queries. Thanks!